# Memcache: /usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so: undefined symbol: memcached_last_error_errno

Tags: jelastic

I'm getting the above error as soon as I enable Memcache at my Drupal application.

- Memcache is within the same environment as Apache
- PHP version 5.5.0
- "extension=memcached.so" added to php.ini
- Error doesn't appear on local dev environment
- Error doesn't appear on another VPS

This issue may be related to an outdated libmemcached version:
https://serverfault.com/questions/456300/upgraded-php-to-5-3-19-and-memcached-stopped-working

Is there anything I can try?

Comment: Contact your hosting provider support

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the attached picture, extension has a name **memcache.so** (also, there are several additional extension versions in the **modules** folder), so it is necessary to specify in the **php.ini** correct file name. Please, change the name and try if it works.

[image: memcache]

Comment: I have a memcached.so (and even memcache.so) file in this folder as configured in php.ini. So this should be fine. Thanks for your hint!